Can I set an email to send when the status in the database changes in MySQL versions 5.6 or 5.7?
Can I set up email notifications to send when the status in the database changes in MySQL versions 5.6 and 5.7? I am trying to send emails directly through the database without using any cron jobs. Are there any possible ways to achieve this in MySQL version 5.6 and 5.7?
